# How to construct a gs:PointStacker parameters using openlayers against geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, wps

I want use openlayers 2.13 dev and geoserver to achive the cluster of points.
I user openlayers 2.13 dev 's "OpenLayers.WPSClient".
here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<title>wps</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./theme/default/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
<script src="lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map,build,gps1,gps2,wpsClient,pointStacker;
        var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                113.458030700684, 34.6213035583496,
                113.84049987793, 34.9462623596191
        );

        var options={
            maxExtent: bounds,
            maxResolution: 0.0014940202236172,
            projection:'EPSG:4326',
            units:'m'
        }
        function init(){
            map=new OpenLayers.Map('map',options);
            build=new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    'buildings',
                    'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wms',
                    {layers:'zhengzhou:buildarea_region',format:'image/png',tiled:true,transparent: true},
                    {isBaseLayer:true}
            );
            gps1=new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    'gps track',
                    'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/zhengzhou/wms',
                    {layers:'zhengzhou:gps_track',format:'image/png',tiled:true,transparent: true},
                    {isBaseLayer:false}
                    );
            gps2=new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
                    'cluster of points',
                    {
                        strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                        protocol:new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                            url:'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wfs',
                            featureType:'gps_track',
                            featureNS:'http://www.ahkeli.com',
                            geometryName: "the_geom",
                            featurePrefix: 'zhengzhou',
                            srsName:"EPSG:4326"
                        })
                    }
            );
            map.addLayer(build);
            map.addLayer(gps2);
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}))
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
            var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(113.663221, 34.756871);
            map.setCenter(lonLat, 1);  
        }
        function cluster(){
            wpsClient=new OpenLayers.WPSClient({
                servers:{
                    local:'/geoserver/wps'
                }
            });

           pointStacker=wpsClient.getProcess('local','gs:PointStacker');
                      **pointStacker.execute({
                inputs:{
                    data:gps2.features,
                    cellSize:30,
                    outputBBOX:{projection: "EPSG:4326",bounds:bounds},
                    outputWidth:1024,
                    outputHeight:512
                },**
                success:function(output){
                    alert(output)

                }
            });

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <button onclick="cluster();">cluster</button>
    <div id="map" class="workmap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but I don't know how to construct the **pointStacker.execute** especially **outputBBOX**, chrome gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined`, meaning the source code's `options.bounds.left`
could somebody give some help!

Answer (score 2):

I do it the right way as follows:



    
    
    
    wps
    
    
    
    
        var map,build,gps1,gps2,wpsClient,pointStacker;
        var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                113.458030700684, 34.6213035583496,
                113.84049987793, 34.9462623596191
        );

```
    var options={
        maxExtent: bounds,
        maxResolution: 0.0014940202236172,
        projection:'EPSG:4326',
        units:'m'
    }
    function init(){
        map=new OpenLayers.Map('map',options);
        build=new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                'buildings',
                'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wms',
                {layers:'zhengzhou:buildarea_region',format:'image/png',tiled:true,transparent: true},
                {isBaseLayer:true}
        );
        gps1=new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                'gps track',
                'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/zhengzhou/wms',
                {layers:'zhengzhou:gps_track',format:'image/png',tiled:true,transparent: true},
                {isBaseLayer:false}
        );

        map.addLayer(build);

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}))
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(113.663221, 34.756871);
        map.setCenter(lonLat, 1);
    }
    function cluster(){

       var wpsFormat=new OpenLayers.Format.WPSExecute();

       var doc=wpsFormat.write({
           identifier:"gs:PointStacker",
           dataInputs:[{
               identifier:"data",
               reference:{
                   mimeType:'text/xml',
                   href:'http://geoserver/wfs',
                   method:'POST',
                   body:{
                       wfs:{
                           version:'1.0.0',
                           url: "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wfs",
                           featurePrefix: 'zhengzhou',
                           featureNS:'http://www.ahkeli.com',
                           featureType:'gps_track',
                           geometryName: "the_geom",
                           srsName:"EPSG:4326"
                       }
                   }
               }
           },
              {
                  identifier:"outputBBOX",
                  data:{
                      boundingBoxData:{
                          projection: "EPSG:4326",
                          bounds:bounds
                      }
                  }
              },
               {
                   identifier:"cellSize",
                   data:{
                       literalData:{
                           value:30
                       }
                   }
               },
               {
                   identifier:"outputWidth",
                   data:{
                       literalData:{
                           value:256
                       }
                   }
               },
               {
                   identifier:"outputHeight",
                   data:{
                       literalData:{
                           value:256
                       }
                   }
               }
           ],
           responseForm:{
               rawDataOutput:{
                   mimeType:"application/json",
                   identifier:"result"
               }
           }

       });

        OpenLayers.Request.POST({
            url:"http://localhost:8081/geoserver/ows",
            data:doc,
            success:function(response){
                    alert(response.responseText) ;
            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

cluster

Comment: Can I use geoserver and the cluster strategy together?